# Query breaking due to single quote

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query like this

```
Select * from table where word like 'Adam\'s apple';
```

But query is breaking even after escaping single quote. Any help?

Error is unexpected "'s" found

Comment: You aren't escaping it correctly.  Use `''` to escape a `'`.

Comment: LIKE but no wild-cards, how come?